# How to Map Array list and sort based on ascendencing order in kotlin

Tags: java, kotlin

How to transform these values in an array list and sort it based on descending order using a single function

var a =[1,2,3]

Each value in the list should be multiplied by 3

ExpectedResult=[9,4,3]

Comment: The order of your expected result is descending, not ascending and 2 multiplied by 3 will yield 6, not 4.

Answer (score 3):

It should be as simple as this

```
var a = listOf(1, 2, 3);
var expectedResult = a.map { it -> it * 3 }.sortedDescending();
```

Comment: @Arunachalamk Exactly, map will iterate over it once and multiply all the numbers by 3 and sorting part will run over it again and sort those mapped numbers.

Comment: In Kotlin do we have any other function to do this logic without two loops

Comment: @Arunachalamk I don't think so, you could write a custom sorting algorithm which would multiply each number by 3 before storing it in the resulting data structure.

Comment: You can use sequences to avoid multiple iterations / creating new lists at each step, but you won't gain anything when it's two steps and one is a sort (which requires a finite number of items, sequences aren't built for that approach). You could make the original list a mutable one, and do the sort in place with ``sortDescending`` (not sort**ed**) so you only create one new list - but make sure it actually matters before you go looking for optimisations